# Exporting face texture animation to Unity

Tags: animation, export, animation-nodes, unity

I'm trying to animate a 3D character's face using 2D face textures. I managed to make them work in Blender using an image sequence but I can't figure out how to export this into Unity. Is there any way to export this or any other method to animate face textures so the animation works in Unity?

Comment: It is possible for sure inside Unity (maybe you have to write your own controller for that), but it definitely not possible to export. So it's more Unity question, consider asking it on Unity forums

Comment: Thanks, good to know it can't be exported, I'll try to to find a solution in Unity  :)